# Python (lists) strings are anagrams or not?

Tags: python

Write a function that checks whetherb two words are anagrams. Two words are anagrams if they contain the same latters. (Example: silent and listen). The header of the function is :
 def isAnagram(s1, s2):

(Hint: Obtain two lists for the 2 strings. Sort the lists and check if two lists are identical)

Write a test program that promts the user to enter two stringd and if theyre anagrams, display 'are anagram' otherwise, 'are not anagram'.

Comment: This is one of the simplest Python programs to write. Please don't ask us to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

the hint tells you exactly what needs to be done.

`list()` function will help you convert strings to lists. 
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list

then look up list methods for `sort()`.
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

then look up list comparison.
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

or just look up `sorted()`
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: (s)he even doesn't need `list`

Comment: @thg435 just went by the way the hint suggested.